# How to generate complementary PWM signal using an IC (integrated circuit)?

Tags: microcontroller, pwm

I am outputting a PWM signal, but the problem is that I can't generate a complementary PWM signal with dead time because this timer channel doesn't support it. So I want to use/buy an integrated circuit (IC) that generates a complementary PWM signal if I feed the PWM signal into it (with dead time). Is there such an IC available on the market?

Comment: Simple ccts use Diode fast OFF and R slow ON into Ciss to affect dead time.

Comment: I did but couldn't find one, that is why I asked to see if someone knows. Thanks.

Comment: I can't help you with a dedicated PWM circuit. To be honest, I thought it often came down to what's in microcontrollers or using a CPLD/FPGA. Is the latter something you'd entertain? You can get what you like in a small cheap IC that way if you're in a position to develop and use it.

Comment: FET bridge driver ICs such as IR2103 have dead time built in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Isolating PWM From H-Bridge](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/109747/isolating-pwm-from-h-bridge)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A typical way of producing what is required (deadtime & complimentary level) is via an R-C network (to produce a delayed waveform) and then feeding the two waveforms into suitable logic gates

[image]

[for completeness, a similar reply by **Andy aka**](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/109747/isolating-pwm-from-h-bridge)

Comment: +1 for using my picture and note that to properly make it complementary one output signal needs to be inverted.

Comment: @Andyaka well I remembered you recently posted on this topic and to distract away from the rapid poster I went and linked that. I had to check by Masters dissertation w.r.t. what I did for an SR drive to redraw it

Comment: what happens when a very high or very low dc signal is fed into the circuitry? :)

Comment: you get a response similar to your typical reply here @dannyf

Comment: sorry that my comment seems to have offended you. you have a great circuit here. I hope it worked.

Comment: Good circuit, JonRB and @Andyaka. Anyone know if this originally came from an old-as-the-hills IC or suchlike? I swear I've seen it in the dim and distant past but can't place it.

Comment: @tonym I designed it about 5 years ago for a job I was working on. I can't rule out that it was influenced by something but nothing springs to mind.

Comment: Mine was 15year ago as part of my final year project where the current loop to the powercore was to be done in discretes.  These days this should be done in software/firmware to ensure minimum pulse width as well

Comment: Thank you @JonRB ,how can I implement the logic gates? Are there IC's available? If so, could you give me an example of an IC? Thanks

Comment: @user203 The logic gates are available as ICs. Check out the 7400 series on wikipedia and the links to similar series from there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7400_series

Answer (score -4):

take the pwm signal and run it through an invertor / NOT gate.

Comment: That doesn't add the dead time the OP wants.

Comment: You've answered a question that you haven't understood, as @OlinLathrop pointed out. And an inverter would actually add a little dead time, even when spelled properly.