# Why are there two NOT gates in a complementary PWM circuit?

Tags: voltage, transistors, current, resistors

[image]

The above is quoted from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/295938/how-to-generate-complementary-pwm-signal-using-an-ic-integrated-circuit). What is the purpose behind two NOT gates? Why not just attach a wire across it since two NOT gates will neutralize each other? For example, 1 will output a 0 for 1 NOT gate and then the 0 will be fed into another NOT gate to produce 1.

Answer (score 3):

The RC circuit will not produce a clean digital pulse.  The edges will be rounded.  Your drawing shows the rounded corners of the output of the RC circuit.

The first NOT gate (actually a Schmitt trigger) sharpens the edges of the pulse back into a usable shape after the RC circuit.  The output is inverted, though.  The second NOT gate inverts the clean pulse to get things back to the original level.

Comment: thank you for your answer :)

Comment: a schmitt trigger is supposed to tolerate uncertain logic levels. So the first schmitt trigger after the rc-low pass is mandatory!

Answer (score 0):

Always be mindful that digital electronics is merely convenient analogue electronics.

The AND gates have an analogue voltage range, consisting of two digital regions (valid logic LOW, valid logic HIGH) and an uncertainty region in the middle.

The RC circuit will produce a slower-moving voltage to drive one AND function. That voltage will not snap sharply between HIGH and LOW so it will spend longer in the uncertainty voltage range. Depending on the rise/fall time, the supply rail voltage/noise, the AND gate design and the particular AND gate on that board, the AND output could switch at different times from circuit to circuit or switch rapidly while the input passes through the uncertainty range.

A Schmitt trigger can remove the uncertainty if it has (fairly) consistent high/low trip voltages with a range between them larger than any input circuit noise plus a margin. AND gates with Schmitt inputs aren't commonplace and plentiful but inverters are.

Hence the two Schmitt inverters, that add the Schmitt trigger while leaving the final logic level unchanged.