# How to avoid square wave parasitic oscillation?

Tags: voltage, transistors, resistors, power-electronics, resistance

[image]

[image]

I try to recreate the circuit from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/623912/why-are-there-two-not-gates-in-a-complementary-pwm-circuit/623917#623917) using discrete components logic gates.  How can I avoid these parasitic oscillations in a square wave in one of its outputs?

Comment: It's not oscillation, just capacitive coupling. Set the source risetime to a more realistic value like 10 or 100ns.  And 10V like the supply I guess.

Comment: For a proper simulation of a discrete circuit with such speeds, you *must* include parasitic inductance of the interconnects which is in the ballpark of 10 nH and more for almost each of the interconnects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design has the wrong threshold to act as Schmitt Triggers on slew-rate limited pulses in order to create "complementary-exclusive transitions" or a "deadtime control circuit."

The transistor delays in your simulation cause these glitches from the XOR arrangement of components.

There are many ways to correct this error.

- If the rise time is above the transistor delays, you might prevent this or make it worse
- define the hysteresis with [resistor ratios.](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Schmitt_trigger) in a Schmitt trigger [image] and input slope to exceed propagation delay.  This is similar to what you have used **but without the added positive feedback R's.**  \$V_{HT}=V+ \dfrac{R_E}{R_E+RC1}\$
- **you need to specify your dead time by slew rate and thresholds then redesign according to this logic.**

[image]
(from your linked earlier question)

(Design Specs are a priori is my motto then test and verify results)

### suggestions

- logic diagram has excessively long connections and could be improved for readability. Compare with the example above.
- trace diagram cropped of critical time base information, show all results in future.
- it is much easier with CMOS logic.

Comment: Hi sir, quoting from "The transistor delays in your simulation cause these glitches from the XOR arrangement of components.", does this mean that this will produce un-even deadtime between the 2 complementary waves if discrete components (discrete transistors are used) ?  Thank you:)