# Add symmetrical deadtime in PWM

Tags: voltage, transistors, power, mosfet, capacitor

[image]
[image]

The above is quoted from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/295938/how-to-generate-complementary-pwm-signal-using-an-ic-integrated-circuit) and I have build the circuit in LT Spice for simulation. The output (highlighted in pink) is as expected that is complementary PWM. However, the question is how do I actually position the wave so that it has same amount of dead time between both waves because it seems that from the picture the waveform is shifted to one side only and not in middle?

Thank you

Comment: This is the 3rd question to the same schematic that is faulty for the answer I gave on your 2nd question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/624948/how-to-avoid-square-wave-parasitic-oscillation.   Scrap this design or do it properly please

Comment: use this https://tinyurl.com/25g9bc36  but Schmitt triggers give more delay

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, thanks sir, for the reply. May I know what value should the resistance and capacitor value be if it were to be 5kHz instead of 500kHz? I tried simulating 5kHz with bigger value of resistance and capacitance but there is no waveform :)

Comment: you would have to wait 100 times longer to see the transition... so change sample time x 100  >Options> Other Options> apply or OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This deadtime CMOS Logic could be performed in BJT or TTL logic as long as you are aware of how this circuit works and its shortcomings.

The deadtime is chosen with a discrete RC circuit and utilized one NOR and one AND gate. Given the tolerances for input thresholds on CMOS are wide, the threshold is critical to each rise and fall time.

One must define what tolerances you need. i.e. a **Spec with temperature range, voltage range, and IC vendor tolerances and family**  then design accordingly.

Schmitt Trigger inputs are good for removing noise but also have wide tolerances for Vgs(th) for each FET and that results in the difference in thresholds so this is of little value unless noisy. It is usually true that all gates within one small-scale IC (SSI) have identical FETs with much tighter matching tolerances but will vary from batch to batch and with temp and Vdd.

With Falstad Sim, It uses ideal Gates with 0 output resistance and 0 rise time at any voltage.  However, XOR gates naturally by design have an asymmetrical prop. delays just like this circuit have some asymmetrical delays due to **variance in mean input voltage, rise time, input thresholds** although the extra gates add no delay here unless modified.  So to simulate all gates in one package, I chose a quad NOR gate and used 2 as inverters to use De Morgan's Law to convert the AND to a NOR.

Then to simulate variable gate thresholds, instead, I create a slider for the input 5V square wave and changed the average value using offset from 1.66 to 3.33 so you can see there is will be a shift in asymmetric time delays **but at least this minimizes the deadtime mismatch to 2%.**  A more precise asymmetry spec demands greater attention to all tolerances above.

Regarding a TTL version since TTL is asymmetric for V vs I by design for symmetrical noise immunity at reduced power, in all TTL families  the TTL threshold is 2 Vbe drops = 2x0.65= 1.3V +/- temp variation but to have an equal delay to thresholds that input into the LPF must be clipped to 2x 1.3=2.6V for symmetry.  Similarly, for single transistor deadtime design thresholds, the signal must be 2 x threshold of say 0.65V @ some Ic mA, but I won't bother here.

[image]
[sim link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgTCAsB0AM8MUgzAUwLQHYQFY5mTEzDAE4AOTWc8gRhxADZYR7dlcNbaAoAJ1aZG4auDCQR5EC1qIeAd0HCwo2kJDkWsBVFrDNSjVp4AlQwe4QDLCDgThoDMI4LCtjngGMxEkr-HgOG5M0ORcLDDkOMhRdqSM9GDMHLBwsLwA5j6BygFEEMb0HJCQUvG4YGXBBbg6kHpGUKWsjFLaiiVSllDwLW11DQadje09NqLDKv2KOJUg5YxB8246jJAypBCLwrSb0jp%20kmNH2uscrVIGdDsl0qy0APrkD7APyJi0JA84L9CP6I9HgAFHhnJg0Vi3a4nVhgJ4vN4fZCvH6pf6Ah4AOVBsA4hz0LGQs1Yewi8NetEgyASzzwsAIOFImHIpEg4lgpFoz1SCHRD14YMO5SJEFo1LuyHJ-KEMUY33w1N%20vIeAP5PCKFS6ezWGxqtlqHWaUyaUkOo2GeikFvIElGs1Nont4AaozUwjW5mMAAdDB6xe6JLQ7tofW6mIHWuBA1B9h1epbjsbtBrJg0nWAGkGajh1dETYYnWGs3ccwAjJqErZkcCYUj7AAezuwYpAmEwEZjlJAABFUABDAAmABcALaoAA6AGdPAB7AB2Q74M4ANlP5ABLIcACynJgAwlOAGYzvhTgcAVz7q8nmM8O8nW6vh6npb464HGVQ0CnQ-XY9LfaThOk7nnOA6oKek4APJer%2086TgAfDO24QVOM6weu8E8I2GbYGQxTEmQwiBhA4FTgAsieGR9nOADkk5TgAMn28hTgAgpi3ZTtRQ7AcekEjn2Q53uuc4ZFOABqQ5TrmgaEQ0HoZsIeIlgceSiIcZpqf4ckQFpihhsaiQnKsvgKb46z7GCRrNGGyCfBKPzcm8rTtt8vx8rwM73OAdzrBQuDSH8dyijUs4jqWomoAOPAxCAHAAGLFrQ0CLPF0DIBwAI9ge0GHoeQHSQxk7fiVU6lRV5VTtVZXFdVACO7EAG4QX2n4NVOKWMIwP4zlOyAZcgPBAA)