Power amplification: from square signal DC to AC square signal
I'm currently developing a circuit to amplify a square signal originating from a PLC. The frequency of this signal ranges from 1 Hz to 20 kHz. The load consists of a small resistance, almost resembling a short circuit, coupled with an inductive element, so I’m dealing with around 5 A at a low frequency.
To tackle this, I'm using an optocoupler to isolate the signal from the PLC, followed by amplification and inversion stages. Additionally, I've integrated a filter to decouple the signals. For ease of power management, I've opted for a power MOSFET H-bridge configuration, simplifying the power source layout.

While electronics isn't my primary expertise, I'm keen to enhance this design. I'd greatly appreciate your insights on potential improvements and whether the chosen components are suitable.
Furthermore, I have plans to incorporate PWM signal control for power regulation in the future. Like this:

Could you offer guidance on this aspect as well?

Welcome! How will the zero volt output be generated from the PLC? Is it digital or analog output?

This H-bridge will have a lot of cross conduction. If your load has both wires available (ie, not one end grounded) then you could simply use a motor controller H-bridge, available from the usual suspects like robotshop at very low prices. You will also get short circuit protection and other perks.

Why is R3 so large?  It reduces the LED current to less than 15 microamps.  You'll never see that.  Also, what peak-to-peak voltage swing do you need at OC1 pin 4 for the circuit to work?

AC-coupling Signal 1 and 2 to the FETS will cause the driving waveform to be differentiated.  You will not have a "square" drive signal to the load across your frequency range.

For each half of the drive bridge, the two gates are about 0.1 V apart - essentially tied together.  No matter how fast the input signal rise and fall times are, and they won't be super-fast because of the response time of the optocoupler, Both FETs are going to be on for a significant percentage of the time.  See the answer about shoot-through.  If you replace R14 and R15 (and 20-21) with 6.8 V zener diodes, you can create a deadband where both FETs are guaranteed to be off no matter how slow the rise/fall times.

@winny Thanks, it is a digital output.

@bobflux i think i get what you said. But, the load it is more complicated than that. the load itself is so large in dimension that can be the ground itself.  Imagine a large plate in the surface of a building, that could be the target (cannot explain why).

That didn’t answer my question. With only one digital output, you can’t achieve three different levels (-12, 0, +12) without external decoding.

@AnalogKid i'm not that familiar with the opto. my idea was to saturate the signal after the amplification so i can assure its a square. the output of the PLC does not look  like perfect it seems that is like filtering or something.

@winny ahmmm... no i cannot generate this signal. i do can generate more pwm signals.

You will need two of them to be able to output the 3 bit pattern shown in your question.

@winny i'm aware, i was thinking in generate 2 PWM signals with the PLC.

Please update your question accordingly.

Your circuit will suffer from "shoot-through", aka "cross-conduction".  This can cause many problems, including low efficiency, heavy load on the power supply, spurious high-frequency oscillations, and destruction of the power devices Q1-Q4, leading to loss of control of the current in the load, which may lead to its demise also.
You may not see these problems when the frequency of the output waveform is low; however, these problems will get worse when you go to implement PWM to control output power.
The problem is this: you're using a single control node (eg: "Signal1") to control a complementary pair of MOSFETs to switch one output node between two low-impedance power supply nodes (0V, and +12V in your case).  While this approach might be OK for some small-signal applications, it is fraught with problems for power applications.  You can see the problem if we consider just one of the arms (or "poles", or "totem poles" if you prefer) of your inverter, as per the image below.
There are at least two mechanisms by which both Q1 & Q2 can be turned on simultaneously.

A break in the circuit causes the voltage at the control node, "Signal1", to become undefined.   (This "broken wire" test is something I like to do to reveal the weaknesses in electronic designs quickly.)
The control node "Signal1" swings from low to high (and vice versa) relatively slowly.  Since this node is being driven by an op-amp, its slew-rate will be relatively slow compared to what is usually obtained when using circuits designed specifically to drive MOSFET arms.


There are several solutions to this.
Solution 1:
You can continue to use complementary MOSFETs for Q1 & Q2, but the control signal must be split up to control each gate independently so that some "dead-time" can be programmed to ensure shoot-through does not occur.
Generating gate drive signals with dead-time is quite simple, here is a starting point for your research:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/625394/341959
Solution 2:
Use non-complementary MOSFETs, eg: N-channel only.  This has the following advantages:
(a) uses the same parts throughout.
(b) N-chan has less resistance compared to P-chan for similar size and price.
(c) N-chan is far more readily available than P-chan.
It does have a problem, however: the upper N-chan MOSFET must have its gate driven above the +12V supply rail.  But this too has a solution, there are many ICs that provide gate drive and protection for N-chan totem poles, here are some links to start your research into this:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/711978/341959
https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/gate-driver-ics/half-bridge-drivers/

Thank you so much for your answer. I'll try this.
