# How can i create a dead time between two signals in Matlab/Simulink?

Tags: matlab, delay, simulink

I have a curcuit which outputs two different  pulse signals from  two different "PWM generator(DC-DC)" block. I will apply these signals to two different mosfets. Thus I need to create a dead time to prevent short circuit.

To achive this, i tried to use "transport delay" and "on/off delay" blocks. The shifting part worked but after applying them to the mosfets the current become weird.

I thought to transfer the signal to the workspace and try shifting there or using "Matlab Function" block but i don't  have an idea how to.

I would appreciate any idea and help.

[image: the circuit]
[image: the current with transport delay]

Comment: Did you ever hear about the term "dead time" and a corresponding hardware approximation proposed by Padé - consisting of resistors and capacitors only?

Comment: Perhaps this similar [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/379279/8713) will help you.

Comment: LvW i know what is "dead time" however  not really have idea about Pade approximation. I am sorry.

Thanks Harry for helping, i edited my title thanks to you. I forgot to mention that I am working in simulink to model a system(could not have chance to work with Ardunio and "real" stuff).

Comment: Could you share the plots illustrating the problem? (that is, "the current become weird")

Comment: I tried to share the plots but i don't know if it worked. I think i have a problem with i.stack.imgur.com.

Anyway if you can't see the plot i am trying to explain with words; the current from non-delayed gate signal has a  good sine shape with pulses. (pulses are forming a sine shape)

However in the plot of the current from delayed gate signal there are two symmetrical region in each cycle  which have peaks.