# How can I calculate the dead time to prevent shoot-through?

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, h-bridge, mosfet-driver, shoot-through

From Figure 1 is evident that to get the dead time I must define the values for RC. E.g my resistor is 220 ohms and capacitor is 0.1uF this gives me 22us at 1-time constant, however, when I measure this on my Pico scope this shows roughly 6.5us at the point of the dead time. Could some one help me understand where the 6.5uS comes from when using these values please ?

[image: Figure 1]

Image source: [How is dead time in a half bridge implemented](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/503865/).

Comment: Depends on the voltage levels those gates perceive as logic 0 and 1. Which gates are they?

Comment: Can you link the source of the picture please.

Comment: Hi Andy I got the picture from you, I am not sure how to link the source to you

Comment: It is clearly some fraction of the RC time constant. That fraction is determined by the logic level thresholds of your gates.

Comment: @DanielBashy - that's why I asked because I should have said (in the picture source) that schmitt trigger gates are recommended. You can copy and paste the link into a comment. Like this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/503865/how-is-dead-time-in-a-half-bridge-implemented/503871#503871 - and note that does show the gates being schmitt triggers.

Comment: @DanielBashy - was it this one: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/109747/isolating-pwm-from-h-bridge/109748#109748 - I do mention schmitt trigger gates.

Comment: Hi Andy yes it is from that link, I know you said use Schmitt trigger gates, but I don't understand how to select the RC values to give me for example 0.2us dead-time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a slightly different circuit than the one proposed by Andy. I used it many times in half-bridge circuits for providing adequate deadtime. I considered a 5-V level for the clock while the AND gates being supplied by a 5-V \$V_{cc}\$ toggle at 2.5 V. If you use different gates, you can modify the below calculations accordingly:

[image]

In this example, the macro calculates a 289-pF capacitor for the wanted 200-ns deadtime.

[image]

Comment: Sorry to bother you I was wondering which simulation software is this from

Comment: Hello, no problem at all. This is coming from Intusoft's IsSpice. You can have similar results with LTspice of course or with the [now free](https://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm) full version of Micro-Cap.

Comment: Thank you for your help